# Segmentation fault (11) on CentOS 6, PHP and APC

Tags: php, linux, centos, apache, apc

I've got a lot of Segmentation fault (11) in httpd error_log on my server.

```
[Tue Nov 20 16:14:41 2012] [notice] child pid 30017 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

It's a CentOS 6.3 with PHP 5.4.8, Httpd and APC 3.1.13.

I've noticed this happens when I use Google Calendar API of Zend framework and when I desactivate APC, this problem stop.

Any ideas ?

My gdb bt :

```
#0  0x00007f0ad0e95da9 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#1  0x00007f0ad0e95f83 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#2  0x00007f0ad0ec88c1 in zend_hash_destroy () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00007f0ad0ebac87 in _zval_dtor_func () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00007f0ad0eadeaa in _zval_ptr_dtor () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00007f0ace4a889f in apc_free_class_entry_after_execution (src=0x7f0adda6bb08) at /var/tmp/APC/apc_compile.c:2003
#6  0x00007f0ace4abdcc in apc_deactivate () at /var/tmp/APC/apc_main.c:948
#7  apc_request_shutdown () at /var/tmp/APC/apc_main.c:1042
#8  0x00007f0ace4a1d25 in zm_deactivate_apc (type=<value optimized out>, module_number=<value optimized out>) at /var/tmp/APC/php_apc.c:407
#9  0x00007f0ad0ec1c44 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#10 0x00007f0ad0e5e085 in php_request_shutdown () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#11 0x00007f0ad0f654a7 in ?? () from /etc/httpd/modules/libphp5.so
#12 0x00007f0adb5e9b00 in ap_run_handler ()
#13 0x00007f0adb5ed3be in ap_invoke_handler ()
#14 0x00007f0adb5f8a30 in ap_process_request ()
#15 0x00007f0adb5f58f8 in ?? ()
#16 0x00007f0adb5f1608 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#17 0x00007f0adb5fd807 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007f0adb5fdb1a in ?? ()
#19 0x00007f0adb5fe79c in ap_mpm_run ()
#20 0x00007f0adb5d5900 in main ()
```

Comment: try starting by getting more information with https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php

Comment: I've added it to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've compiled APC from the trunk and I don't have the problem any more !